# How to Amend Javascript object property

Tags: javascript, object, responsive-design, modernizr

I'm using a responsive style hamburger  menu on my webpage, however the resize width of the menu does not match the CSS media queries break point (I suspect this is because it does not take into account the scroll bars)

To avoid this problem, i'm using modernizer to detect the media query break points. Is it possible to change  the resize width of the object below?

In short I want to make the resize width = 768 **if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 768px)')) ?**

```
   var pluginName = "slimmenu",
        defaults =
        {
            resizeWidth: '768', // use modernizer to align with MQ breakpoint
            collapserTitle: 'Main Menu',
            animSpeed: 'medium',
            easingEffect: null,
            indentChildren: false,
            childrenIndenter: '&nbsp;&nbsp;'
        };
```

Many thanks,

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with? How to write an `if` statement? (`if (condition) { ...do stuff... }`) How to assign a value to a property? (`foo.bar = value;`) Something else?

Comment: Hi Felix King, thanks for the reply, yes, how to implement the if statement to work with the resizeWidth property.   I want to write code that will set resizeWidth to 768, only if Modernizer.mq returns 768.   However, I've just realised this may not be possible because variable scoping ? Modernizer is being loaded onto the page via a CDN

Comment: `if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 768px)') { defaults.resizeWidth = 768; }` would do that.